# Installation fails when using provisioner in packers for installing nvm

Tags: node.js, nvm, packer

I followed the below steps in provisioner to install nvm on a new azure vm but i am unable to install. The source doesn't load the sh script.

```js
{
  "variables": {
    "client_id": "{{env `ARM_CLIENT_ID`}}",
    "client_secret": "{{env `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET`}}",
    "resource_group": "{{env `ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP`}}",
    "storage_account": "{{env `ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT`}}",
    "subscription_id": "{{env `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`}}",
    "ssh_user": "palm",
    "ssh_pass": null
  },
  "builders": [{
    "type": "azure-arm",

    "client_id": "{{user `client_id`}}",
    "client_secret": "{{user `client_secret`}}",
    "resource_group_name": "{{user `resource_group`}}",
    "storage_account": "{{user `storage_account`}}",
    "subscription_id": "{{user `subscription_id`}}",

    "capture_container_name": "images",
    "capture_name_prefix": "packer",

    "os_type": "Linux",
    "image_publisher": "Canonical",
    "image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
    "image_sku": "16.04-LTS",

    "azure_tags": {
        "ticket": "palm"
    },

    "location": "East US",
    "vm_size": "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }],
  "provisioners": [{
    "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
    "inline": [
        "curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash",
        "source ~/.bashrc",
        "nvm install v8.9.4",
        "nvm alias default v8.9.4",

        "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
    ],
    "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
    "type": "shell"
  }]
```

I am getting the following error when i run the build script. Not sure why it say like nvm command is not found.

```js
./packer build -var-file=variable.json ubuntu-16.04-nodejs.json 
azure-arm output will be in this color.

==> azure-arm: Running builder ...
    azure-arm: Creating Azure Resource Manager (ARM) client ...
==> azure-arm: Creating resource group ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-j5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm:  -> Location          : 'East US'
==> azure-arm:  -> Tags              :
==> azure-arm:  ->> ticket : palm-972
==> azure-arm: Validating deployment template ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-j5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm:  -> DeploymentName    : 'pkrdpj5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm: Deploying deployment template ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-j5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm:  -> DeploymentName    : 'pkrdpj5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm: Getting the VM's IP address ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName   : 'packer-Resource-Group-j5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm:  -> PublicIPAddressName : 'packerPublicIP'
==> azure-arm:  -> NicName             : 'packerNic'
==> azure-arm:  -> Network Connection  : 'PublicEndpoint'
==> azure-arm:  -> IP Address          : '40.71.227.46'
==> azure-arm: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> azure-arm: Connected to SSH!
==> azure-arm: Provisioning with shell script: /tmp/packer-shell063897685
    azure-arm:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
    azure-arm:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    azure-arm: 100 12540  100 12540    0     0  40290      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 40321
    azure-arm: => Downloading nvm from git to '/home/packer/.nvm'
    azure-arm: Cloning into '/home/packer/.nvm'...
    azure-arm: Note: checking out '7ad6d98cedde01809e32d56ab8ced064f6f28175'.
    azure-arm:
    azure-arm: You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
    azure-arm: changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
    azure-arm: state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
    azure-arm:
    azure-arm: If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
    azure-arm: do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
    azure-arm:
    azure-arm:   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
    azure-arm:
    azure-arm: => => Compressing and cleaning up git repository
    azure-arm:
    azure-arm: => Appending nvm source string to /home/packer/.bashrc
    azure-arm: => Appending bash_completion source string to /home/packer/.bashrc
    azure-arm: => Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:
    azure-arm: /tmp/script_8684.sh: 3: /tmp/script_8684.sh: source: not found
    azure-arm:
    azure-arm: /tmp/script_8684.sh: 4: /tmp/script_8684.sh: nvm: not found
    azure-arm: export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
    azure-arm: [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
    azure-arm: /tmp/script_8684.sh: 5: /tmp/script_8684.sh: nvm: not found
    azure-arm: [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
    azure-arm: WARNING! The waagent service will be stopped.
    azure-arm: WARNING! Cached DHCP leases will be deleted.
    azure-arm: WARNING! root password will be disabled. You will not be able to login as root.
    azure-arm: WARNING! /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail and /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original will be deleted.
    azure-arm: WARNING! packer account and entire home directory will be deleted.
==> azure-arm: Querying the machine's properties ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-j5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm:  -> ComputeName       : 'pkrvmj5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm:  -> OS Disk           : 'https://ubuntujava8.blob.core.windows.net/images/pkrosj5kfs33y6n.vhd'
==> azure-arm: Powering off machine ...
==> azure-arm:  -> ResourceGroupName : 'packer-Resource-Group-j5kfs33y6n'
==> azure-arm:  -> ComputeName       : 'pkrvmj5kfs33y6n'
```

How to run a nvm dynamically using packer ? Is there any other way to install nvm using provisioner ?

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same error. I solved it by running:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

And then using it.

Comment: Thanks @Osmond, for me it appeared that the source of .bashrc was happening before nvm was fully installed, making it really difficult to debug what was going wrong. Your code block worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the first error

```
tmp/script_8684.sh: 3: /tmp/script_8684.sh: source: not found
```

`source` is not a valid sh built in, you should use `.` instead. I.e.

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I tried with . ~/.bashrc instead of source ~/.bashrc. But getting the same error as well.